# Emacs Org-Mode TODO List Missing Items

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs24

I've recently begun to learn org-mode and have been following a couple of online tutorials such as this: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9116?page=0,2

I've encountered a problem where the TODO items that are listed in my main test.org document are not showing up in the list view: `M-x org-todo-list`

For example, test.org:

```
* Example
** TODO We have an issue
*** TODO What is the problem
```

`M-x org-todo-list` displays:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with `N r': (0)[ALL]
```

Why are my TODO items missing from the global list? Has anyone else encountered this problem? I'm currently running:

```
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0)
Org-mode version 8.0.6 (Elpa install)    
MacOS 10.6.8 x86 64-bit
```

Org-mode portion of .init.el file:

```
; Org-mode
(require 'org-install)
(package-initialize)
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)

; Enable S-TAB MacOS
(add-hook 'term-setup-hook
    (lambda () (define-key input-decode-map "\e[Z" [backtab])))
```

Note the adding either of the following commands does not solve the problem:

```
(setq org-agenda-include-all-todo t)
(global-set-key "\C-ct" 'org-todo-list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the `org-agenda-files`.

```
(defvar dir-where-you-store-org-files "~/rog/")
(setq 
 org-agenda-files 
 (mapcar (lambda (x) (concat dir-where-you-store-org-files x))
         '("file1.org" "file2.org" "file3.org")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `org-agenda-files`, which you can do easily with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-variable RET org-agenda-files`. Then just add the full path to your test.org file. You can add more files by selecting `INS` in this buffer.